# Flatpak apps with System-wide installation in AppCenter

Tags: appcenter, flatpak

Only user-wide installation is done when installing Flatpak apps in AppCenter, with normal or admin user. System-wide installation can be done in Terminal. But then it won't be reflected in AppCenter. Which means no update notification for those system-wide installed apps.

Is it possible to do system-wide installation in AppCenter?

Answer (score 1):

It is not currently possible.

However, there is [ongoing work](https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/pull/1308) to support this. I can't give a specific date as to when that feature would be ready, but I would hope it would be complete by the release of elementary OS 6.0

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to manage system-wide Flatpaks from within AppCenter.
You have to add a system remote to make this functionality available.
To add Flathub as a system remote you would use the following command in Terminal.

```
$ sudo flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists --system flathub \
  https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

Once a system remote has been configured, Flatpaks can be installed system-wide directly from AppCenter.
Just note that it might require a restart for the option to appear.

Comment: I found the system-wide option available in the AppCenter like months before. I think eOS is updated and officialy support it now.

Comment: Right you are! The [PR](https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/pull/1308) was merged on August 28th, 2020. Though you still need to add a system-wide remote for the option to show up in AppCenter.

Answer (score -2):

Developers of the Elementary OS are not answering questions on forum. Report it on Elementary OS github. Maybe they will answer. But I doubt.  Besides I recommend to read the guide: [flatpak guide](https://itsfoss.com/flatpak-guide/)

Comment: Developers do answer questions on StackExchange occasionally. GitHub is not the correct place for questions, so please don't suggest people ask questions there. It should only be used for bug reports and feature requests.

Comment: Really? I have never seen any professional answer from them.